# Weird flickering in Chrome only on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, windows-7

Our website uses a lot of modern stuff like mouse parallax, scroll parallax, infinite scroll, css clip animation, etc. and most of them uses hardware accelerated animations with 
`transition: translate3d(...)`.

I spend a lot of time for browser testing, try and error till it worked on every browser – I thought – then last week a client notify me a bug in latest Chrome browser on Windows 7 Professional, the project images flicker by moving mouse or scrolling site. Well, we all know the Webkit flickering bug thing, so I tried all workarounds I could find, like adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

or

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

or

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

to the flickering elements, but with no luck. Then I disabled all parallax mouse and scroll effects, used native scrolling, etc. but with no changes at all. 
Now I asked myself is it really the Webkit flickering thing or is it just Windows 7 Professional? Or is it both together? with Windows 7 Ultimate and Chrome everything works!

Does anyone had the same issue? Any ideas how to solve or to reduce this unwanted effect?
I'm just going nuts!
[This is the link to website](http://grafinet.ch), it's unique to Windows 7 Professional 32 Bit with Chrome (35.0.1916.153).

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day with try & error I finally found the solution. It wasn't the Webkit flickering bug, following CSS selector gave me this issue in Chrome on Windows

```
div.container > *:before { ... }
```

so I replaced it with

```
div.container > header:before, div.container > section:before, div.container > footer:before { ... }
```

That's all. Maybe this helps someone.